# Tag islands of records

Tags: sql, sql-server, gaps-and-islands

I have this data set:

| Id | PrevId | NextId | Product | Process | Date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | NULL | 4 | Product 1 | Process A | 2021-04-24 |
| 2 | NULL | 3 | Product 2 | Process A | 2021-04-24 |
| 3 | 2 | 5 | Product 2 | Process A | 2021-04-24 |
| 4 | 1 | 7 | Product 1 | Process B | 2021-04-26 |
| 5 | 3 | 6 | Product 2 | Process B | 2021-04-24 |
| 6 | 5 | NULL | Product 2 | Process B | 2021-04-24 |
| 7 | 4 | 9 | Product 1 | Process B | 2021-04-29 |
| 9 | 7 | 10 | Product 1 | Process A | 2021-05-01 |
| 10 | 9 | 15 | Product 1 | Process A | 2021-05-03 |
| 15 | 10 | 19 | Product 1 | Process A | 2021-05-04 |
| 19 | 15 | NULL | Product 1 | Process C | 2021-05-05 |

Per product, I need to tag consecutive/islands of records that have the same **Process** like:

| Id | PrevId | NextId | Product | Process | Date | Tag |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | NULL | 4 | Product 1 | Process A | 2021-04-24 | 1 |
| 4 | 1 | 7 | Product 1 | Process B | 2021-04-26 | 2 |
| 7 | 4 | 9 | Product 1 | Process B | 2021-04-29 | 2 |
| 9 | 7 | 10 | Product 1 | Process A | 2021-05-01 | 3 |
| 10 | 9 | 15 | Product 1 | Process A | 2021-05-03 | 3 |
| 15 | 10 | 19 | Product 1 | Process A | 2021-05-04 | 3 |
| 19 | 15 | NULL | Product 1 | Process C | 2021-05-05 | 4 |

A product goes through multiple **Process**-es and can go through the same one more than one time.

I basically need to produce the **Tag** column, the logic behind it is consecutive records with the same **Process** should be grouped together but a caveat is that the same process can appear further down the line but should be treated as a new group.

I have tried the basic windowing functions (`ROW_NUMBER` and `DENSE_RANK`) but the problem is that those count *within* the partition and not *across* partitions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't have to validate prevId and nextId (that is if your data is already correctly ordered) you could try the following:

```
WITH cte AS(
SELECT *
       , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Product ORDER BY [Date]) x
       , DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY Product, Process ORDER BY [Date]) y
  FROM T1
  WHERE product = 'Product 1'
),
cteTag AS(
SELECT Id, PrevId, NextId, Product, Process, [Date], x-y AS Tag_
  FROM cte
)
SELECT Id, PrevId, NextId, Product, Process, [Date], DENSE_RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY Product ORDER BY Tag_) AS Tag
  FROM cteTag
ORDER BY [Date]
```

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I need. The `ROW_NUMBER` + `x-y` trick is pretty clever.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `lag()` to determine where the values are the same.  Then a cumulative sum :

```
select t.*,
       1 + sum(case when process = prev_process then 0 else 1 end) over (partition by producct order by id) as tag
from (select t.*,
             lag(process) over (partition by product order by id) as prev_process
      from t
     ) t;
```

[Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/bec2f/6) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Seems a bit off, please see this [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/bec2f/3)

Comment: @JohnMarkGabrielCaguicla . . . Adding `1` is really not significantly off, but I modified the answer.

Comment: It's not just off by 1, records with different *Process*-es are getting grouped together. Please see the fiddle I linked in a previous comment.

Comment: @JohnMarkGabrielCaguicla . . . I see.  There was a typo in the answer.  I fixed the typo and think this is the simplest answer.